# "bin/console debug:autowiring" no muestra nada

Tags: symfony4

Estoy usando el comando `php bin/console debug:autowiring` para listar los alias a los servicios de Symfony tal y como se ve en el tutorial de su documentacion [Symfony: Servicios](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony/services#play)

Pero mientras que veo que en su ejemplo hace una lista completa de todos los alias/servicios, en mi terminal cuando ejecuto dicho comando no me muestra ningún listado. El comando se ejecuta correctamente sin ningún error pero no muestra ningún listado. ¿Debo instalar algo para ver esta información correctamente? ¿O tal vez se deba a otra causa?

Answer (score 0):

Lee la documentación de Symfony:

```
https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/debug.html
```

Asegurate que tienes bien configurado el archivo services:

```
services:
# default configuration for services in *this* file
_defaults:
    autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
    autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
    public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                        # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                        # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.
```